# Why does WinSCP open local directories with .exe files slowly?

Tags: filezilla, winscp, hung

If I open local folder with a few .exe files with WinSCP (and FileZilla too), it hangs for a little while and then opens the directory. On remote FTP directory this doesn't happen.

Why does this happen and how can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP (FileZilla possibly too, not sure) loads icons from the EXE files (and few other formats). That can take a time, if there are lot of EXE files in the local folder.

In WinSCP, there's a hidden configuration option that you can use to turn off loading icons.

Run WinSCP once like this:

```
winscp.exe /rawconfig Interface\LocalIconsByExt=1
```

Reference: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawconfig

WinSCP does not load the icons from remote files EXE files (it would have to download them). Only file extension is used to select an icon for remote files.

Comment: Additionally, because loading the icon means “opening” the file, the on-access AV scanner will run, slowing down things *a lot*.